# closing msaccess.exe in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am working on creating a vb.net program i have a button that when clicked on will browse for MDB files (code 1) and when selected will execute some lines of code that will populate all of the macros within the access database into a combo box (code 2).   The problem i'm having is MSACCESS.EXE process is not closing after code 2 runs. I've tried a couple different things like objAccess.CloseCurrentDatabase() none of which are working.. Any ideas on what i'm doing wrong?

code 1

```
Private Sub CommandDBPath_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CommandDBPath.Click
    Dim dialog As New OpenFileDialog()
    dialog.Filter = "Access database (*.mdb)|*.mdb"
    If DialogResult.OK = dialog.ShowDialog Then
        TextDBPath.Text = dialog.FileName
    End If
    SelectDatabaseMacro()
End Sub
```

code 2

```
Private Sub SelectDatabaseMacro()
    Dim objAccess As Object  '' Access.Application
    Dim i As Long
    Dim path As String
    path = TextDBPath.Text
    objAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
    objAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase(path)
    For i = 0 To objAccess.CurrentProject.AllMacros.Count - 1
        TextReportMacro.Items.Add(objAccess.CurrentProject.AllMacros(i).Name)
    Next
    objAccess.CloseCurrentDatabase()
    objAccess = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding an `objAccess.Quit` statement after you `objAccess.CloseCurrentDatabase()`.

Comment: objAccess.Quit does not resolve this either.. Using Access 2010 if that matters at all.

Answer (score 2):

To abruptly kill the process,

```
For Each p As Process In Process.GetProcesses()
    If p.ProcessName = "MSAccess" Then
        p.Kill()
    End If
Next
```

Or for a more "graceful" approach, try this,

*The process must have a windows interface (window) in order to work.*

```
For Each p As Process In Process.GetProcesses()
If p.ProcessName = "MSAccess" Then
    p.CloseMainWindow()
End If
Next
```

Comment: Might not be the best way but this worked -
Added after SelectDatabaseMacro() in code 1